# python histogram with float numbers

Tags: python-2.7

I want to  make histogram with float numbers

how i can do this?

5.7328103184852415, 6.684121509452399, 8.548130419807434, 10.04982184387077, 9.955605739934846, 11.566719030267505, 8.406258334477634, 16.93518193949364, 2.49161180597924, 7.583070189384996
and more (range 0..20)

Comment: Did you try googling "how to make histogram python"?

Comment: yes dont help me

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. You need to show your efforts at arriving at a solution. Your last step should be to ask a question on StackOverflow, and you should be prepared to elaborate on what you've tried. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you should probably try using matplotlib:
[Link](http://matplotlib.org/)